# Site wide redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new website, hosted with Heroku, about 3 weeks ago and have since decided I wanted to change its domain name. I was trying to figure out how to do a site wide redirect and I'm thinking of going with something like in my application controller (add a before filter):

```
def new_domain
  redirect_to url_for(:controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :id => params[:id], :host => 'http://newdomain.com'), :status => 301
end
```

This obviously will not work with all actions and will fail if the url is passing additional parameters. I was wondering if there is something more general I can do so I don't have to have a bunch of if else clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
params[:host] = 'http://newdomain.com'
redirect_to url_for(params), :status => 301
```

'url_for' take a hash and by changing the 'host' in the params, it should go to the new host with the rest of the params.

Comment: This looks much cleaner. I suppose I should put that in an unless statement to ensure I'm not redirecting people, or more importantly Google bots, going to the newdomain...

Answer (score 1):

As recent versions of Rails now adhere to the Rack interface and can incorporate [Rack middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) it might be worth taking a look at [Canonical Host](http://coderack.org/users/tylerhunt/entries/6-canonical-host). I haven't used it myself but at first glance it sounds like it might be nice solution.